# Legendary drops from raid bosses regardless of your lockout?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

We know Legion raid bosses can drop legendary items and the chance remains in different difficulties. So you can go in Raid Finder, Normal, Heroic and Mythic to kill the same boss(es) 4 times for loot and you have 4 chances to get a legendary.

My question is different, though. **Is it possible to get a legendary item from a raid boss you have already killed this week on that difficulty?** You can use another bonus roll on that boss, but you can't loot normal items from it and legendary items are special personal loot, so this is somewhat tricky.

I've heard rumors about this being possible, but haven't seen this, yet. We even cleared Heroic Emerald Nightmare a couple of times when recent server lags made it hard to go Mythic, so my people were sure to get another shot at a legendary.

PS: This is only about **raid** bosses. Dungeon bosses grant loot every time you queue for them, so they always have their legendary drop chance.

Comment: Since legendary items are personal loot i don´t think it´s possible. We did not even get gold on our second kill so it seems that there is no roll for the special loot active if you have a lockout on that boss.

Comment: @MartinH. Gold is like normal loot, so that doesn't surprise me. Legendary rolls look more like bonus roll loot, just without having to click the button. And those always work.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it seems very unlikely. They would probably not want to encourage people to run raids multiple times a week with no loot just for the chance at a legendary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get a legendary from a boss that you've already killed.

There are basically two loot tables in play when looting a (raid)boss.

- The Boss loot table consisting of all the items you can find in the dungeon journal
- A bonus loot table consisting of artifact power, blood of Sargeras, runes (LFR), gold and **legendaries**.

Whenever you kill a boss you'll always have acces to the bonus loot table regardless of the loot system.

The boss loot table works a bit different if you use bonus rolls or are using the personal loot system. If you don't win anything with either a roll or the persoloot RNG you'll simply get gold.

Now if you have already killed a boss you are **locked out both loot tables**. This means that you won't get any gold artifact power or legendaries. Since a bonus roll will always roll for the Boss loot table (with gold as a backup) it's not possible to get artifact power, BoS, runes or a legendary if you've already killed a boss.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but do you have a source for it? I can't find anything concrete on how the tables interact.

Comment: @KizTrap Unfortunately I don't have a link or something. I've dicussed the topic for quite a while now with my guild mates. The only "source" I have is  personal experience from playing and talking to other players.